# uniqueness of pointer to type_info object

Tags: c++

I was looking through the object factory chapter in the book referenced [here](https://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00657.html). The `TypeInfo` class above which is intended to be unique for each C++ class type uses a pointer to `std::type_info` under the hood. I'm wondering if this is guaranteed by the latest standards to be unique for a given type?

If that is not guaranteed to be unique is there an alternate implementation of TypeInfo that can achieve such a guarantee?

Comment: How is the linked class "_intended to be unique for each C++ class type_"? How does it rely on uniqueness of pointers to `std::type_info` objects?

Comment: read the equality operator https://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00608.html#7eeb3efc28b414524d16958f04d9d7d5

Comment: Nothing in the information you've linked to suggests reliance on uniqueness of `std::type_info` objects.   If the `operator==()` and other operators dereference the pointers (`std::type_info *`) and compares the result using `std::type_info::operator==()` [which is likely in practice] it will not be comparing their addresses either.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see anything in the current standard draft making a guarantee that there will be only one `std::type_info` object referenced by `typeid` expressions for the same type, nor do I see any in C++98.

But I also don't see how the linked code would care about that.

Comment: It's used here https://github.com/dutor/loki/blob/master/Reference/Factory.h which presumably requires a uniqueness guarantee

Comment: @user3882729 The `TypeInfo` operators are implemented to compare _values_ of `std::type_info` objects, not their object identity or pointers to them. `Get` returns a reference to a `type_info`, not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about uniqueness of `std::std::type_info` pointers, but there are `std::type_index` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) type which is *"a wrapper class around a std::type_info object, that can be used as index in associative and unordered associative containers"*. So I read this as this index is unique for each given type.